# $y''-2y'-4x^2y+x^2 \sqrt{8\pi}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am attempting to solve the following second-order ODE, but the integrals I'm getting in it are just getting really nasty and I'm getting lost. I believe the answer should be in the form of the $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ functions (integrals of $\sin (x^2)$ and $\cos (x^2)$ respectively), but I'm not positive on that one.

For the record, this is not a homework question. This ODE came up when attempting to solve a pretty interesting integral I came up with on my own. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have particular initial conditions in mind?

Comment: Including constants of integration @Semiclassical.

Comment: Can you solve the homogeneous equation and then try variation of parameters?

Comment: The homogenous solution appears to be $y_h(x) = A_1 y_1(x) + A_2 y_2(x)$, with $y_1 = e^{x(1-x)}H_{-3/4}(\sqrt{2}x)$ and $y_2  = e^{x(1-x)} {}_1F_1(3/8;1/2;2x^2)$, according to Mathematica. Let now $y = A_1(x)y_1(x)$ or $y = A_1(x)y_1(x)+A_2(x)y_2(x)$ to determine a particular solution.

Comment: @Dmoreno, that's what I got when I put it into Wolfram.  My confusion is when we have to evaluate the Wronskian of these two and integrate. Is there any nice form for these, even in terms of the hypergeometric function and hermite?

Comment: For particular solution: there is some constant that will work.  For the homogeneous equation, Maple does it in terms of `KummerM` and `KummerU`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''-2y'-4x^2y+x^2 \sqrt{8\pi}=0$$
$$y''-2y'-4x^2(y- \frac14\sqrt{8\pi})=0$$
Change of function :$\quad u=y- \frac14\sqrt{8\pi}$
$$u''-2u'-4x^2u=0$$
Change of function :$\quad u=e^{x-x^2}v$
$$v''-4xv'-3v=0$$
This is an ODE of the Airy kind.
$$v=c_1\text{Ai}(X)+c_2\text{Bi}(X)\quad\text{with}\quad X=2^{-4/3}(4x+3)$$
Ai and Bi are the Airy functions.